# What affects the kind of date (local vs. UTC vs unspecified) on JTXJobClass.StartedDate?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-workflow-manager

I am accessing the JTXJobClass.StartedDate for a JTX Job (with IJTXJob3).  I am getting an unspecified DateTime.Kind value.  The value appears to be UTC (iirc, WMX always stores UTC in the database but I'm questioning that since the DateTime.Kind is unspecified). The value comes from the started_date field of the JTX_JOBS table and its values looks like UTC to me.

Is there a WMX configuration that would make the [DateTime.Kind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx) on the JTXJobClass.StartedDate return as `Utc`? Or `Local`?

Or is it safe to *assume* that the unspecified value is `Utc`?  Instinctively, this is my first approach (because it is easy), but then I started to think about what could go wrong if that assumption doesn't hold true.

Comment: I'm just guessing here.. but the local time was probably inserted and underlying that is a unix millisec time. So if you rehydrate it to a date and time, it would be the original local time. The problem I have found is when client APIs rehydrate a unix time and then automatically localize a date, e.g. javascript Date. They localize an already local date and you have to undo the offset.